Issue while cloning a repository from AWS Code Commit?
While cloning a repo from AWS Code Commit, I got an error like these...
fatal: repository 'https://git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/eduvocate/' not found
how to fix this?
I need to clone this repo and pull the changes from all branches.
I have only access to Code Commit all other option such as IAM role is all denied which is "ACCESS DENIED"

Does your IAM user or IAM role have explicit denies related to your code commit? Are there any permission boundaries that prevents your IAM user  or role from pulling source code? Have you properly configured your git credentials from the cloning client?

Yeah, I have no access on IAM user and role, and how to configure git credentials from cloning client?

Check out the answer below.

Since you don't have access to an IAM role, you will need to request for a GIT credential that you can use to clone the CodeCommit repository.
Check out this article from AWS: Setup for HTTPS users using Git credentials
